# Rails Devise Ajax Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise, modal-dialog

I'm trying to do an ajax modal login with devise on Rails(4.1).  I can't seem to get it to work.  I sign in and nothing happens, despite my logs saying I redirected with 200.  Then I hit refresh, and it says I'm logged in.  Why isn't it redirecting after sign in? Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is the modal partial:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), :remote => true, :format => :json, class: 'sign-in') do |f|  %>

    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Email', class: "form-control center-block" %>

    <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password', autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control center-block' %>

    <%= f.submit 'log in', class: 'center-block btn btn-sp btn-lg'%>
<% end %>
```

Here is the SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

def create
 resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "home#index")
 return sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
end

def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
 scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
 resource ||= resource_or_scope
 sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
 return render :json => {:success => true, :redirect => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)}
end

def failure
  return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
end
end
```

And here is the javascript:

```
  $('.sign-in').bind('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr){
  console.log(data);
  if(data.success){
    $('box').prepend('<p>signed in<p>')
  } else{
    console.log('didnt work')
    $('box').prepend('<p>login failed</p>')
  }
})
```

Here are the server logs:

```
 Started GET "/admin/accounts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-29 11:01:19  -0800
 Processing by Admin::AccountsController#index as JS
 User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 6  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 Account Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 Account Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts"   ORDER BY "accounts"."organization" ASC
 Rendered admin/accounts/index.html.erb within layouts/suite (12.4ms)
 Rendered layouts/application.html.erb (11.2ms)
 Rendered layouts/privacy-terms.html.erb (0.1ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 38ms (Views: 33.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Comment: What does your Devise routes look like? Are you sure that the Devise sessions#create is going to your create action? Try throwing a `binding.pry` in that action to make sure.

Comment: Yes here's my devise routes: devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations', sessions: 'sessions', passwords: 'passwords', unlocks: 'unlocks'}

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
def create
  resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "home#index")
  sign_in_without_redirect(resource_name, resource)
  @after_sign_in_path = after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end

def sign_in_without_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
  scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
  resource ||= resource_or_scope
  sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
end
```

Rails will, by default, render a view called 'create'. Since you're submitting the form `remote: true`, it will render a javascript view at 'create.js.erb'. You can put whatever logic you want in there like:

```
(function() {
  window.location = "<%= @after_sign_in_path %>";
})();
```

And then you can forget about the javascript event listeners.